# Devise OmniAuth and Devise-otp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am new to rails.
I want to do a google authentication app using Devise gem. (i.e) SignIn with Google after successful login by user and then I have to display otp view page (using Devise-otp gem)

Is it possible to implement those 2 features using Devise Gem in single app ?
If Possible can give me some tutorial links or some steps.

I completed Signin with google after that I don't know how to use Devise-otp to proceed second-step-verification process. so please help me.
I referred below links but it confused

https://github.com/AsteriskLabs/devise_google_authenticator

http://www.techhui.com/profiles/blogs/add-two-factor-authentication-to-your-rails-app-with-devise

Answer (score 0):

You can use `active_model_otp` gem for this purpose.
[Active model otp](https://github.com/heapsource/active_model_otp)